# Devise token auth another user login

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, ruby-on-rails-5, devise-token-auth

I am developing an application through Rails.
I need the ability to login to another user with admin account in devise token auth gem

When user log in, authHeaders are stored in the browser cookie.
Determine user by authHeaders value.

ex)

{ %22access-token%22:%22"access-token value"%22%2C

%22token-type%22:%22Bearer%22%2C

%22client%22:%22"client value"%22%2C

%22expiry%22:%"expiry value"%22%2C

%22uid%22:%22"uid value"%22}

in my controller 
returns a new token value when admin clicks user id

```
def login_as 
  user = User.find(params[:user_id])
  user_new_token_data = user.create_new_auth_token
  ## return new access-token, token-type, client, expiry, uid in browser cookies format same value

end
```

I want to change the return value to a browser cookie value and log in as another user, but I do not know how to put it in the cookie.

I would appreciate your help. Thank you